# A={1,2,3},B={1,2,2,3}. Is B⊆A? And is B⊂A?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I was thinking yes to the first question and no to the second. They are equal sets right even though B has duplicate elements.

Comment: Sets do not have duplicate elements. However, an enumerative representation of a set may have duplicate entries. So $\{1,2,2,3\}$ is the set with the three elements $1$ and $2$ and $3$, i.e., $B=A$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$A=B$$

So yes to the first and no to the second.

Don't worry about the duplicates. When we're talking about sets, only the existence matter and not how many times. Sets that counts how many times it appears are referred as multisets.

Answer (score 0):

The article on [multisets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) on wiki is of interest:

> In mathematics, a multiset (or bag, or mset) is a modification of the
> concept of a set that, unlike a set, allows for multiple instances for
> each of its elements. The positive integer number of instances given
> for each element is called the multiplicity of that element in the
> multiset. As a consequence, an infinite number of multisets exist
> which contain only elements a and b, but vary in the multiplicities of
> their elements:
>
> The set {a, b} contains only elements a and b, each having multiplicity 1 when {a, b} is seen as a multiset.
> In the multiset {a, a, b}, the element a has multiplicity 2, and b has multiplicity 1.
> In the multiset {a, a, a, b, b, b}, a and b both have multiplicity 3.
>
> These objects are all different, when viewed as multisets, although
> they are the same set, since they all consist of the same elements. As
> with sets, and in contrast to tuples, order does not matter in
> discriminating multisets, so {a, a, b} and {a, b, a} denote the same
> multiset

And later in the page :

> Inclusion: A is included in B, denoted A ⊆ B, if
>
> $\forall x\in U, m_A(x)\le m_B(x)$

Therefore seen as sets then $A=B$ and seens has multisets since $m_A(2)=1\le m_B(2)=2$ and other multiplicities are the same, then $A\subset B$ and $A\neq B$.

Comment: I set it community as I mostly quoted wikipedia.